# Use Asus Eee Pc as a remote for pc

Tags: wireless-networking, bluetooth, eee-pc

I have a [Eee PC 701SD](http://uk.asus.com/product.aspx?P_ID=n1cnZPE6vk5gJo2b)

I have since become bored of it, and now in the mood to "Hack" it. My current home set up is a pc connected to my TV and I watch internet shows etc on it.

My only real idea is to somehow use the Eee pc as a wireless mouse and keyboard for my pc (Connecting wirelessly or via bluetooth)

Can anyone point me in the right direction

Comment: You're missing an e in the title...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to install [Synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/) on both computers. It would let you use the keyboard and mouse-pad on your Asus as keyb/mouse on your media PC.

> Synergy lets you easily share a single mouse and keyboard between multiple computers with different operating systems, each with its own display, without special hardware. It's intended for users with multiple computers on their desk since each system uses its own monitor(s).
>
> Redirecting the mouse and keyboard is as simple as moving the mouse off the edge of your screen. Synergy also merges the clipboards of all the systems into one, allowing cut-and-paste between systems. Furthermore, it synchronizes screen savers so they all start and stop together and, if screen locking is enabled, only one screen requires a password to unlock them all.

Answer (score 1):

You could just install VNC. That's what I used to do with my media PC. Worked great.